# Google Drive APIs Java Client authentication

Tags: android, authentication, google-drive-api

I'm developing a chat application like whatsapp. To implement file sharing feature among chat users, I'm using the Java Client api of Google Drive within my app. The issue I'm facing is that API requires user to authenticate each time the file sharing action is performed. What I'm looking for is, user should authenticate only first time the file sharing feature is performed and not repeatedly.

If there are any workarounds, please suggest.

Comment: If you dont want user to login every time, then you can use oauth offline access. check this link https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline. To implement this you have to include access_type='offline' in your oauth code.

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between authorise and authenticate